# Running Linux on Windows at school without actually installing linux

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

The school here wants to teach basic Linux and Unix things like terminal and CLI.
The problem is, installing things is not allowed. So, dual boot is out of the question. Just running windows 8.

Next, the systems aren't powerful enough for any VM. Running ancient systems on 4GB RAM. Currently, the school is using Cygwin. But we can't properly use commands like  `chmod` and the like.

I am thinking of

1. Using git bash terminal. Don't know if permission commands will work properly on Windows 8 or not.
2. Using live ubuntu on USB. The system will be read-only, so `mkdir` and `chmod` is out. Or is there a way to do this? Please suggest.
3. Using Slackware or Puppy OS.
4. As suggested in comments, running a distro online.

As a student what can I suggest to the teachers?
Option 3 seems the most viable choice. Any suggestion is welcome.

---

**EDIT:**
persistent storage is not a requirement. On the contrary, it is welcomed, cleaning up after all the experiments.

Thank you

Comment: Live Ubuntu isn't read-only. You can do mkdir and chmod. Changes are lost when you reboot, unlike with persistent disks.

Comment: @muru so all the commands like `chmod` and `mkdir` will work properly without leaving anything after shutdown. is it?

Comment: If you stick to the live system, yes. If you mount the local hard disk and mess with it, no.

Comment: @muru thanks. will try it out.

Comment: Another option, depending on your Windows version, is SUA: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @will go with live USB. seems the easiest without any trouble. good enough for teaching the basics. thanks again

Comment: git bash is cygwin

Comment: there are online emulators available ... https://bellard.org/jslinux/

Comment: Have you tried running a VM? 4 GB of RAM is actually quite a lot.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I doubt a 6+-year-old dual-core pc will do the trick.

Comment: @jsotola almost forgot about it. thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @Doc Have you actually tried? Without wanting to go all old-timer, I was running VMs back in 2008 on machines a lot less powerful than that.

Comment: @PhilipKendall great. so if they need anything more powerful I can go with VMware or virtualbox. is using in this manner allowed?

Comment: See if you can allocate a single machine to actually install Linux on (it does not need to be fancy), then set up accounts and SSH on it and get the students to use PuTTY from the Windows machines to connect to it. Real multi-user experience and everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any distro with a live image should work.

**A word of caution, though:**  One COULD use a live linux to mount the windows system disk and then `cat /dev/zero > /dev/windowsdisk` and thus destroy the windows installation.

A more secure setup would be to boot the PCs from the network and start an already preconfigured system.  That would offer teachers more control over what is happening.

Debian-Edu might be helpful.

And you probably should have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/27454/tips-on-setting-up-a-linux-classroom-environment

Comment: +1 for the caution. I have complete faith in the students. ;)

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to run Ubuntu Live from a USB stick with persistent storage, meaning you partition your USB stick for Ubuntu to use as storage and save your settings. The following link explains how to do this:

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/amp/
The commands you have mentioned (`mkdir and chmod`) should work on Ubuntu live, however without the persistent storage it will be wiped along with any other changes and configurations made when you reboot

Another option available is to instead of using Ubuntu Live, install Ubuntu on to the USB disk. The following link explains how to do that:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.dionysopoulos.me/portable-ubuntu-on-usb-hdd/amp/

Comment: persistent storage is not a requirement. On the contrary, it is welcomed, cleaning up after all the experiments.

Comment: In that case the Ubuntu Live or other live distro should work. The commands you are looking for will work. Alternatively you could suggest setting up a cheap/inexpensive server where the students could SSH into if you are just going to work on the CLI. You can utilize PuTTY in that case

Comment: I tried live ubuntu 16.04 on VM on my pc. tested `chmod` and `mkdir`. seems to work fine.  is there anything else I need to test before I suggest it to school?

Comment: You should be all set. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to spin up cloud linux instance. There are multiple cloud service providers. (Eg: AWS, Azure, GCP, Alibaba ...etc) Even you can create free account. Only thing you need to have is internet connectivity and ssh client tool like putty or xshell (there are many more ssh client tools).

Or else you can use a linux protable softwares which can run via pen drive. Anyway if you use light weight / minimal installations you won't need any high resources.
eg: https://mashtips.com/best-portable-linux-distro/

Answer (score 0):

I love [copy.sh](http://copy.sh/v86/) for this kind of stuff. They offer "root access" in a browser based terminal to a VM that is restored to a clean state when you're done.

They use "v86" emulation, which is 32 bit and boils down to a Pentium 1 instruction set, see https://github.com/copy/v86 and especially the *How does it work?*  section.

Comment: creating custom emulator using locally stored ubuntu 16.04 iso won't work. what is wrong?

Comment: The VM technology they use apparently uses an x86 emulation (32-bit) and not 64 bit. Try another image or just use their http://copy.sh/v86/?profile=archlinux archlinux one :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Linux Live USB Creator](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5488-linuxlive-usb-creator.html) has an option which allows you to use Windows as a host and [virtualize a Linux OS booted from a LiveUSB](https://www.techspot.com/guides/809-run-linux-from-usb-drive/) it creates. The third tickbox in Step 4 must be checked to enable this option, as shown in the picture below. It would require each PC or each student have a 4GB or larger USB flash drive, and because of your slow PCs, a very lightweight distro is recommended; [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.com/) is explicitly supported.

[image: Launchable option]